# Swift Tableview reusable cell issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am having an issue with what I think is reusable cells in a tableview cell, unfortunately I can't work out how to force the state of the cell. I am fairly sure this is the issue because when I reload the tableview everything is displayed correctly. It's only when I scroll that I start to see issues, if I once again reload the display corrects itself.

This is the correct display :

[image]

and the incorrect display after scrolling about :

[image]

my cellForRowAt code :

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyGoalCell", for: indexPath)
        
        let name = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
        let date = dateManager.dateAsString(for: items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].date!)
        
        
        if tempDate != date {
            
            // show header
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = date
            
            tempDate = date
            
        } else {
            
            // don't show header
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
              
        }
        
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(date),\(name ?? "")"
        
        return cell
    }
```

Thanks for any help, I have been stuck with this for a couple of days, very new to TableViews - thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you use viewForHeaderInSection instead of trying to create 'headers' in the cell itself. You'll probably find that resolves your issue and gives you the nice scrolling effects that come with proper headers.

Comment: What is `tempDate` I guess that's the culprit. It might be override when you do ` tempDate = date`, not in the order you think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

can be invoked in any order. It isn't called consistently from 1 to N, so logic with `tempDate` works not as planned. Better do some pre-work and make an array with indexes where you place headers. For example

```
struct Pair : Hashable {
    var i : Int
    var j : Int
}

//Somewhere one time before the first reloadData

var hasIndex : Set<Pair> = []
var tempDate: Date = Date.distantPast

for i in 0..<sections {
    for j in 0..<rows[i] {
        let name = items[i][j].name
        let date = dateManager.dateAsString(for: items[i][j].date!)
        if tempDate != date {
            hasIndex.insert(Pair(i: i, j: j))
            // OR items[i][j].showHeader = true
            tempDate = date
        } else {
            // OR items[i][j].showHeader = false
        }
    }
}

...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyGoalCell", for: indexPath)
    let name = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
    let date = dateManager.dateAsString(for: items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].date!)

    if hasIndex.contains(Pair(i: indexPath.section, j: indexPath.row)) {
    // OR if items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].showHeader {
        cell.textLabel?.text = date
        tempDate = date
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(date),\(name ?? "")"

    return cell
}
```